# django dict to excel, httpresponse to download excel file

Tags: django, excel, python-3.x, httpresponse, xlsx

I have a dictionary:

```
a = {'name0': [1, 2, 3], 'name1': [4, 5, 6]}
```

how can I download this data as xlsx file via Django framework and httpresponse?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert this data into excel using Pandas and then save this file then make a downloadable link and display it on UI using httpresponse.

Comment: pandas export data in the current directory, I need to make them available for download without adding a new file to the current directory each time.

Comment: Pandas export data to the current directory, I need it to be downloaded directly.